# KnockoutJS: bind values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internationalization, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to bind translations to my view. My code gets the translations from Sharepoint 2013 as an array. Example:

`[ {de: "Titel", key: "pageTitle"}, {de: "Stichwortsuche...", key: "searchPlaceholder"}, {...} ]`

How can I use knockout to bind this to my view? I'm using the mapping plugin by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an easy solution myself:

```
var browserLang = navigator.language.substr(0, 2);
var translations = {};
$.each(translationArray, function (i, obj) {
    translations[obj.key] = obj[browserLang];
});
```

Bindings are KO as usual (`data-bind="text: pageTitle"` and so on).

Attention: This solution won't handle languages you don't have translations for - don't forget to implement a fallback functionality!